# How do I express this in regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

Should be **TRUE**:

```
 kword_search1 = “#include”;
 kword_search2 = “#include<iostream.h> #include”;
 kword_search3 = “#include<iostream.h> #include<iostream.h> #include”;
```

What I’ve done so far:

```
if( /include$/g.test(kword_search)
```

The problem here is that it only matches at kword_search1

Comment: I just tested `/include$/g.test('#include<iostream.h> #include<iostream.h> #include')` and it returns true as well...

Comment: What should not match ?

Comment: You don't need the `g` flag on your regex, but it should work anyway.

Comment: How did you end with those invalid string delimiters ?

Comment: maybe its not the regex that causes the error, i should take a look at it again

Comment: @dystroy Yeah, I just saw it, as soon as I asked. +1 nice catch.

Comment: @fireflieslive: the quotes you use `“` are not the correct one. They have a unicode value of 8220 instead of 34, which is the correct one: `"`

Answer (score 0):

You want to test if a line ends with `include` word. Yes?

Then your own solution is correct. The problem is this:

the quotes you use `“` are not the correct one. They have a unicode value of 8220 instead of 34, which is the correct one: `"`

Comment: Yes but those " " are not really present in my code, i just did that for presentation purpose, but thanks, gonna look on it again

Comment: haha... it's better not to try fancy presentation in code  :P